# after adding DOM manipulation before ajax call, the dom is not retaining after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

**[DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/n4m9584b/)**

**Current Flow ScreenShoot for Ref :**

[image: Screen Shot of Current flow]

Iam Adding a class to element and trying to give focus. for static elements its working fine. but whenever i call ajax request. the class which i added is not retaining its getting removed.

JS :

```
$('#search-refine-bar').on('click', function(e) {
    var eventNode = e.target.nodeName;
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight').removeAttr('tabindex focus style').css({
        "border": ""
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(eventNode + " --------------- " + 'In Progress adding focus');
        $(e.target).attr({
            tabindex: "-1",
            focus: "focus"
        }).addClass('highlight').focus().css({
            "border": "1px solid #f00"
        });
        alert(eventNode + " --------------- " + 'Done status')
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: $('refineChil') what should this select?

Comment: @reyaner : I was using that for separate function, plz ignore that. i have edited the question/

Answer (score 0):

After the first click, everything look fine for me.

Your click event is on the div that contains everything, so you are marking also `<p>` tags etc.
Im not sure if you want this...

The probelm is, when you click agian some where, you are delting everything with this code...

```
$('.highlight').removeClass('highlight').removeAttr('tabindex focus style').css({
    "border": ""
});
```

And im not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this code..

Im just guessing, are you trying something like this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/589hq620/

But for your question, removing this code is the answer...

Comment: I cannot add ajax in JSFIDDLE, if you see the options and the checkbox, that triggers an ajax call.
Thanks !

Comment: i would like to help you, but i dont understand what your problem is. Where in your fiddle, should i click, to see your error.. explain.

Comment: I have added a screenshot, like exactly how it is currently working. please let me know if still need a clear picture. 
Step 1 : Before Ajax 
Step 2 : After adding class
Step 3 : After Ajax Request
Thanks!